# Regexp to match any group of string within an address

Tags: javascript, regex

***For example if I have this address;***
820 10th Avenue New York, New York 10019

***I want to match the following in regexp;***
820 10th Ave 
820 10th Avenue 
820 10th Avenue New York

the above is the only expected format

my code so far

```
var re = /(^\d*\D*\w*)/i; 
var str = '820 10th Avenue New York, New York 10019';
```

it should work like this;

```
if(re.test('820 10th Avenue')) console.log('pass'); // pass
if(re.test('820 10th Ave')) console.log('pass'); // pass
if(re.test('820 10th')) console.log('pass'); // pass
if(!re.test('820 9th Ave')) console.log('fail'); // fail
if(!re.test('820')) console.log('fail'); // fail
```

Comment: Do you have more sample input and sample output?

Comment: Can you explain what sort of inputs should *not* match?

Comment: is your data always in this order ?

Comment: Flagged as too broad. (narrow the scope!)

Comment: Question is far too broad without knowing use case , data source, search source, reliability of formatting and precision needed

Comment: please show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to check whether an input string is part of a given string, you could use [**`String.prototype.indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

   ```
   var str = '820 10th Avenue New York, New York 10019';

   str.indexOf('820 10th Avenue') > -1 // true
   str.indexOf('820 10th Ave') > -1    // true
   str.indexOf('820 10th') > -1        // true
   str.indexOf('820 9th Ave') > -1     // false
   str.indexOf('820') > -1             // true
   ```

   More specifically, compare with `0` to see if it's a prefix:

   ```
   var str = '820 10th Avenue New York, New York 10019';

   str.indexOf('820 10th Ave') === 0 // true
   str.indexOf('20 10th Ave') === 0  // false
   ```
2. Add pattern matching, according to your given examples:

   ```
   function testAddress(input) {
       var address = '820 10th Avenue New York, New York 10019';
       var re = /^\d+(\s\w+){2,}/;
       return re.test(input) && address.indexOf(input) === 0;
   }

   testAddress('820 10th Ave')             // true
   testAddress('820 10th Avenue')          // true
   testAddress('820 10th Avenue New York') // true

   testAddress('820 9th Ave')     // false
   testAddress('820 10th')        // false
   testAddress('820')             // false
   ```

Comment: Thanks Leo, that worked! but why did you choose indexOf() instead of search()?

Comment: @Parker There's not much difference for this case. `search` accepts RegExp as argument, non-RegExp arguement will be converted to RegExp. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search It is used to find a pattern, while in this case you just want to find a substring, `indexOf` is enough.

Comment: testAddress('820 10th') returned true

Answer (score 0):

I don't even think I need regexp for this. This worked for me!

```
    var str = '820 10th Avenue New York, New York 10019';
    var n = '820 10th Ave';
    var position = str.search(n);

    if (position != -1) {
        console.log('matches')
    }else{
        console.log('no match');
    }
```

Comment: The pattern address will always be something in this format
 **820 10th Ave** or **820 10th Avenue New York**
you will never have only the number e.g **820** or **820 10th Ave New York**

Comment: So... your answer still returns **matches** for **820**.